# Replace the output of a module containing local variables by their actual value

Tags: replacement, scoping, variable

I want to construct a function as the output of a Module, but I obtain the local variables as part of the output. This is a problem when I try to construct many of these functions in a parallel table, because all these local variables appear to die when the parallel computations end.

Minimal example:

If I write

```
Module[{i = RandomInteger[{0, 100}]},
 Function[x, x + i]
 ]
```

I obtain

```
Function[x$, x$ + i$197286]
```

Now the problem:

If I write

```
t = ParallelTable[
  Module[{i = RandomInteger[{0, 100}]},
   Function[x, x + i]
   ],
  4
  ];

Through[t[5]]
```

I obtain

```
{5 + i$19726, 5 + i$21792, 5 + i$20597, 5 + i$19520}
```

and the variables like `i$19724` have no value.

If I use Table instead of ParallelTable I get what I want

```
{60, 13, 62, 13}
```

I found a workaround by doing

```
Module[{i = RandomInteger[{0, 100}]},
 With[{ei = i}, Function[x, x + ei]]
 ]
```

obtaining

```
Function[x$, x$ + 15]
```

which is EXACTLY what I want. I prefer to have concrete values inside the functions, even if I don't use parallelization.

But I have to introduce a new variable. And this is a problem if there are many of these constants inside the function. Is there a way to solve this problem **without using a new variable**?

Comment: Function has the attribute "HoldAll". That is why i is not replaced by its value. You can force the replacement by writing: With[{i = i}, Function[x, x + i]]  instead of: Function[x, x + i]

Comment: Is that "good practice" ? the syntax coloring gets all red.

Comment: @julianhaddad I think it's fairly standard. If you don't like the coloring, you can always rename the inner variable to something else, e.g. `With[{j=i},Function[x,x+j]]`